# Add a click handler for option dropdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, dom-events

I have an option select element in HTML.

```
<select>
   <option value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
   <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to create automated testing for this web page using selenium.
so, naturally I have added `change` listener for the select element.
It works on all the select elements across the product, except one.
The specific one that isn't working has an event listener at the application level which manually resets the selected index to 0.

So, by the time my (testing) event listener shown below is triggered, the value has already been set to 0.

```
activeElm.addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log(activeElm.selectedIndex);
});
```

So is it possible for me to listen to click events on option selection.

Alternatively, I tried using mouse event listener.
But I couldn't use mouse event listening for select options. My initial idea was to use mouse event listening thereby getting xy co-ordinates and manually trigger the click using selenium. However, mouse x,y co-ordinates show up as some negative numbers which seems completely off the charts.

P.S.
To add more clarity, I record all the events by launching my app in nw.js (this is where my new event listeners are injected) and write the captured events to a file.

Then at a later time my Selenium Java application will be reading the file and triggering the events one by one.

Comment: I am having hard time understanding this line "by the time my (testing) event listener below is triggered" Is your event listener injected in the page?

Comment: If it's injected. then where is it injected before the app's script or after the app's script

Comment: @karthick I inject the events when I capture the events in record phase. using nw.js

Comment: I am not familiar with nw.js. But the event listeners you create are not triggered. If you event listener has to capture something before your app can change that. You have to inject your script before the app's mainjs. In this way your event listener is registered before the app's event listener

Comment: @karthick My event listeners are indeed triggered but since the event listeners are first come first serve basis, the application's event listener is triggered first and the application event listener changes the selected index. By the time injected event listener is triggered, the selected index has already been changed.

Comment: @karthick
My event listener cannot be added before the application's because the dom element is dynamically created by the application and event listeners are registered immediately on creation by the application.

Comment: you can still move your event listener ahead of all the listeners , make your event listener to capture events on capturing phase by adding 'true' at the end of the event listener  
activeElm.addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log(activeElm.selectedIndex);
}, true);

Comment: @karthick It doesn't print the actually selected index. I suppose it doesn't force the sequence.